# How to read characters and get length of characters in a text file?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a java text file named "text_in.txt" which contains

```
IDESOFMARCH
```

which is 11 characters in length, how do I go about finding the length of this file and appending an 'X' character to the end of H so that the text may be broken up into blocks of 2 characters each to be used for RSA encryption/decryption.

Example: `ID ES OF MA RC HX`

I have a main() which calls the encrypt method from my rsa.java file (files, private, public keys)

```
code.encrypt(files, 17, 2773);
```

files contains "text_in.txt" and "text_out.txt" and a boolean true which opens both files.

The main is calling this:

```
public void encrypt(FileInOut files, int e, int n) {



//Get the in file length and add a 'X' if uneven character blocks
    if((files.length() % 2) == 1)
      files.write("X");

//Print a 0 in the encrypted file to represent the end of a line
    if(files != char)
      files.write("0");
```

Comment: Why not use valid cryptographic padding instead? Much more reliable than doing it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to read a text file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well borrowing an answer from [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file-in-java)

```
String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("text_in.txt")));
int len = str.length();
```

Comment: Thank you @WillShackleford this was very helpful, I tried to search for it before but could not find it.